# Distinct value for multiplie column as one

Tags: postgresql, group-by, distinct

I have a table `transactions` with columns : `id_transaction`, `credited_person`, `debited_person` and a table `users` with `id_user`.
For each user I want a list of all the people with whom he made a transaction (it does not matter if the user is debited or credited)

[image: result wanted]

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `users` to `transactions`, group by user and use [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select u.user_id,
  string_agg(distinct
    case 
      when u.user_id = t.credited_person then t.debited_person
      else t.credited_person
    end,
    ','
  )
from users u left join transactions t
on u.user_id in (t.credited_person, t.debited_person)
group by u.user_id
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the count of person instead of a list ?

Comment: @J.doe Instead of `string_agg()` use `count(*)` or `count(distinct case...end)`.